# Unable to install website msi using command line in Window10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, c#-4.0, window

**Overview** : Installing a MVC3 Website using C# command line. The application installed correctly in Win7, win8, server 2008 & 2013. The same installer not working in window10 after configure IIS correctly.

**Error Message** : 
Product: Web Client -- This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again.

**Error Message in Event log(MsiInstaller)** :
Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Web Client. Product Version: 3.x.xx. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: xxxx. Installation success or error status: 1603.

**Installer code** :

```
 Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = msiexec.exe;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments ="/qn /i \"" + Settings.InstallationDirectory + "Website\\WebClient.msi\"";
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

unable to see installed website in IIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I discovered there was some configuration problems with the Conditions Editor (Requirements on Target Machine)

[image]

**Walkthrough:**

Go to the setup project setup and Launch the Conditions Editor.
[image]

Right click on the IIS Condition and view the properties

[image]

Check Condition Formula; it should as the following:
(IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND **IISMINORVERSION >= "#1"**) OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6"

If you want to install on IIS Version 7.5 and above then use the below condition formula:

***(IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#10"***

In Windows 10 Default IISMINORVERSION  value  = 0 (but my code is 1 and i have modified my setup accordingly).

How to fine MIN and MAX Value :

1. Open system registry
2. Move to following location "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters"
3. Left side panel find the MIN and MAX default values  (refer below the screen)[image]

Above the changes working for me and let me know if any

Comment: First time I've used Visual Studio installer templates and maybe this is specific to VS2015 (I don't know) but I didn't realise straight away that after you make these changes you have to right-click on the project then click on 'Build', then right click on the project again and click 'Install'. Just clicking install to test it doesn't rebuild it for some reason.

Comment: Excellent catch/workaround for this.  But a suggested condition like `(IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#10"` looks wrong, it would fail on `7.0` or `8.0` etc., be careful about doing an `AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1"` without thinking this through?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Search Target Machine condition properties

**IISMAJORVERSION, IISMINORVERSION** Root Value to vsdrrHKLM

Answer (score 0):

Remove the <> from Launch condition of build and again build the project, this is how I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install `IIS 6 Management Compatibility` (more exactly `IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility`) feature within `Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools` to make it work on IIS 10.